# Python not detecting requested URL for Google Firebase

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently trying to link a Realtime Database with Python Flask.

Currently when linking Python to the database however, it does not detect it. Instead, it defaults to: "The requested URL was not found on this server."

What could be the source for this issue? Here is my code so far, if it helps provide any context.

```
from firebase_admin import credentials, db
import json

cred = credentials.Certificate("App Interface\key.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {'databaseURL': 'https://console.firebase.google.com/u/2/project/<MY PROJECT NAME>/database/<MY PROJECT NAME>-default-rtdb/data/~2F'})

ref = db.reference('/')


#Problem occurs here. I can not add any information to the database without it 
#causing the previously mentioned error.
users_ref = ref.child('users')
users_ref.set({
    'alanisawesome': {
        'date_of_birth': 'June 23, 1912',
        'full_name': 'Alan Turing'
    },
    'gracehop': {
        'date_of_birth': 'December 9, 1906',
        'full_name': 'Grace Hopper'
    }
})
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the Freibase stuff but your `databaseURL` looks incorrect. Although for the JavaScript library, this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start#add_the_js_sdk_and_initialize) describes determining the `databaseURL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's URL of the Firebase Realtime Database *console*. This is the `databaseURL` that you need:

[image]